# List only showing last Array from data passed in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm getting data back from using this line

```
.onReceive(model2.$postsById) { postById in
                        print("MODEL2 \(postById)")

                    }
```

that looks like this:

```
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", album_id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", name: nil, path: "public/1584106997200-astronomy-space-abstract-galaxy.jpg"), Test.PostById(id: "7ac7ff5f-4b4b-458f-b9a6-491813dbe97d", album_id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", name: Optional("California Wind "), path: "public/1584106997230-California_Wind.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "d804c511-fdd6-453c-816d-fbe501b0ba8d", album_id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", name: Optional("Cosmic Love "), path: "public/1584106997710-Cosmic_Love.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "094e5b65-f0b2-4a5d-8c20-c6fa3d733325", album_id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", name: Optional("Happy Sixth "), path: "public/1584106997890-Happy_Sixth.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "f148fd8e-6896-492b-8e5a-c99072cad562", album_id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", name: Optional("How it Began "), path: "public/1584106998000-How_it_Began.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: nil, path: "public/1584040897839-smiley.png"), Test.PostById(id: "4897093c-7b7b-4e1b-b757-6d11cd56f0c2", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: Optional("California Wind "), path: "public/1584040897843-California_Wind.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "a74de5c6-6161-45c4-add8-d530eabcb8f0", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: Optional("Cosmic Love "), path: "public/1584040898074-Cosmic_Love.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "b74233f6-ae11-42e9-89d4-94fec754e46b", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: Optional("Happy Sixth "), path: "public/1584040898205-Happy_Sixth.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "7f297fd6-e8d3-4e64-82c8-464fed40e196", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: Optional("How it Began "), path: "public/1584040898289-How_it_Began.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "0ccadf9b-3ca9-4528-ae4f-c4a646e04075", album_id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", name: Optional("It Doesnt Need To Be More Than That "), path: "public/1584040898397-It_Doesnt_Need_To_Be_More_Than_That.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", album_id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", name: nil, path: "public/1584045867007-71188186_249463072641040_8764351972645011456_n.jpg"), Test.PostById(id: "ffb572f9-bc40-412f-9514-e413da06da8e", album_id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", name: Optional("Shameless Life Wisdom Sendoff "), path: "public/1584045867009-Shameless_Life_Wisdom_Sendoff.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "98b9bbfa-346e-4571-81a2-38afd8c5353c", album_id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", name: Optional("Simmering "), path: "public/1584045867657-Simmering.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "65ccf88b-5754-4981-ab06-cf4cdc93eca8", album_id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", name: Optional("Skewls Owt "), path: "public/1584045867892-Skewls_Owt.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "6b350c4d-c6b1-4679-b7d5-2c3bd33459f5", album_id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", name: Optional("Still Not Rite "), path: "public/1584045868127-Still_Not_Rite.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", album_id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", name: nil, path: "public/1584039156755-add.png"), Test.PostById(id: "c311604f-0bfc-4930-bfdf-fcf5592483b9", album_id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", name: Optional("A Typical Ride Out "), path: "public/1584039156755-A_Typical_Ride_Out.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "984857d1-5d39-4e66-9379-e8346f7e5b43", album_id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", name: Optional("Because For Everything There Is Someone "), path: "public/1584039156941-Because_For_Everything_There_Is_Someone.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "1919b016-6a6e-4793-8305-71207d9518ae", album_id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", name: Optional("California Wind "), path: "public/1584039157156-California_Wind.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", album_id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", name: nil, path: "public/1584040654626-home-icon.jpg"), Test.PostById(id: "42a3c308-8d03-47a9-9723-d66013f6fcca", album_id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", name: Optional("A Typical Ride Out "), path: "public/1584040654632-A_Typical_Ride_Out.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "938f642d-db6f-4519-b575-1e1598f5fae7", album_id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", name: Optional("Because For Everything There Is Someone "), path: "public/1584040654799-Because_For_Everything_There_Is_Someone.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "6313b82f-672f-4cc7-9ccb-ae0e24e2fef8", album_id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", name: Optional("California Wind "), path: "public/1584040655221-California_Wind.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", album_id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", name: nil, path: "public/1584038265741-Profile-img-icon.png"), Test.PostById(id: "4e9d5c31-d48e-4d0a-8f26-ba67d1ac39c2", album_id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", name: Optional("Prophet 7 "), path: "public/1584038265742-Prophet_7.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "71b80407-2434-445e-8e0b-30e1a45293a7", album_id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", name: Optional("Rubber Ducky "), path: "public/1584038265907-Rubber_Ducky.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "0069ba6a-85c2-48d8-b5bd-d0e70c84bea2", album_id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", name: Optional("Shameless Life Wisdom Sendoff "), path: "public/1584038265996-Shameless_Life_Wisdom_Sendoff.mp3")]
MODEL2 [Test.PostById(id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", album_id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", name: nil, path: "public/1584032744268-Screen Shot 2020-01-21 at 11.55.48 AM.png"), Test.PostById(id: "eea069f2-df72-462f-853d-25af33f4812c", album_id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", name: Optional("Kindergarden "), path: "public/1584032744268-Kindergarden.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "4a13a1cf-4f9e-4ba0-b67e-3a77d0290c8d", album_id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", name: Optional("Lulu Is the Cat I Like Best (1) "), path: "public/1584032744426-Lulu_Is_the_Cat_I_Like_Best (1).mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "4f5d4390-e179-4bce-8cb0-a074fc958653", album_id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", name: Optional("Lulu Is the Cat I Like Best "), path: "public/1584032744541-Lulu_Is_the_Cat_I_Like_Best.mp3"), Test.PostById(id: "dbe3a0be-73ea-4f22-add4-71ab62605103", album_id: "0c40b732-7173-44c9-b183-6b0a77f481ae", name: Optional("Lust "), path: "public/1584032744605-Lust.mp3")]
```

... plus more

Which I believe is all my data

I am passing `model2.postsById` from my ContentView into another View called Album:
`NavigationLink(destination: Album(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)) {`

And using it like this:

```
struct Album: View {
    var post:Post
    var post2:[PostById]

 var body: some View {
             VStack {
                List(self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == post.id }) { post in
                   Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
                }
           }
      }

}
```

Which displays nothing in the List.

If I use it like this:

```
List(post2) { post in
                   Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
                }
```

It only displays the data from the last array coming back from the results on the top.

Why is this happening and how can I make it work so I can get the results for this line to work:

```
List(self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == post.id }) { post in
                   Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
                }
```

And have post2 iterate through all my data like:

```
.onReceive(model2.$postsById) { postById in
                        print("MODEL2 \(postById)")

                    }
```

does

Comment: What happens when you remove the filter? When are you setting the .id property on your post instance variable?

Comment: If I remove the filter and just use post2 I'm getting the last array from my data I displayed at the top. I know I'm getting the id because I can use it and see it in my `struct Album` right away when I run the app

Comment: And your postsById I assume is a @environmental, right. I see where you're passing it. Okay, this might be silly but let's try. Try making your instance variable var post2:[PostById] = [] create your own init and in that init method append the incoming [PostById] array to your existing array; worth a try...

Comment: I tried this `Album.init(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)` `var post:Post
var post2:[PostById] = []
    
 init(post: Post, post2: [PostById]) {
    self.post = post
    self.post2 = post2
    print("POST2 \(post2)")

}` and it didn't work. post2 is only displaying the last array out of the data on the top of this page

Comment: I realized if I pass `model2.postsById`, `post2: self.model2.postsById` outside of the List in my ContentView it displays all the data. So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps if you use a ForEach nested inside of a list it will properly display the full array.

```
List{
    ForEach(self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == post.id }){ post in
        Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
    {
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is that `NavigationLink(destination: Album(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)` is in a List so it's only getting `self.model2.postsById` for one piece of data. I'm wondering how I can pass pass `model2.postsById` as a whole or make it identifiable by the same id as `post`

Comment: Here's my Views for this app: https://gist.github.com/DDavis1025/a78a71e856ce0f50307b0d19dc34505b

Comment: I asked the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873858/how-to-pass-full-data-into-another-view